# HTTP URL Parameter Security for UrlFetchApp.fetch()

Tags: security, web, google-apps-script

I have (1) a Google Sheets spreadsheet with a bound Google Apps script that uses [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to make requests to (2) my own Google Apps Script web application (implemented using [doGet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)).

When I am making a request, I am adding HTTP parameters with sensitive information, for example:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/D83jfe2F543wj5s6U4Ws4I/exec?**firstname**=John&**lastname**=Smith&**email**=johnsmith@hotmail.com&**SSN**=123456789

Q: Is adding sensitive parameters like this safe from a security standpoint? It is HTTPS, so as far as I am aware, the URL should be encrypted end-to-end.

---

NOTE: One might argue that someone could have infected the user's computer with a virus to see which URLs the user visits, but I just ran this test to find out where GAS requests originate from, and they do not even originate from the user's computer, but rather from Google Servers in Mountain View (so it seems that everything is happening "behind the scenes" in a secure manner?):

```
function findMyIP() {
  var url = "https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address"; // IP finder website
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // Execute a GET request from GAS to that website
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response.getContentText()), 'Website Display');
}
```

---

EDIT - PICTURE FOR CLARIFICATION FOR A FUTURE READER (credit to Sandy Good's answer):

[image]

Comment: Should have been on [security.se] where it would be closed as a duplicate of a [duplicate](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/38688) of a duplicate of a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your input Alex. I am trying to understand how the requests work once they are issued. For clarification (and as you mentioned, this might be suited for the webpage you posted), do you know if HTTPS requests issued IN BETWEEN Google Apps Scripts stay within Google infrastructure throughout? Or can a client get access to the web calls being made (for example under Chrome Developer Tools)? Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: The interactions are done "in a secure manner."  The `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` request can only be issued from a Google Server.  There is no way to run that from the user's (client's) browser.  Apps Script uses HTTPS ("S" on the end), but I'm not sure if it is using the latest and best encryption method.  You *can* make a POST request instead, and receive it with `doPost(e)` and put the data into the payload.

Comment: @SandyGood Thanks a lot for this input! It resolved my concerns. If you submit it as the answer I can mark it correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interactions are done "in a secure manner." The UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) request can only be issued from a Google Server. There is no way to run that from the user's (client's) browser. Apps Script uses HTTPS ("S" on the end), but I'm not sure if it is using the latest and best encryption method. You can make a POST request instead, and receive it with doPost(e) and put the data into the payload.

Comment: Sandy, thank you again for your very useful advice! I am writing a security specification. I have one follow up question. When I execute a request with UrlFetchApp.fetch() to my own GAS web app, I notice that the request is not from a logged in Google account (or may not have the appropriate authentication). The request then will not work unless I publish the web app as allowing "Anyone even anonymous" to use it. Do you know if there is a way around this since I am only communicating from GAS to GAS? There may be a way to send an authenticated request.

Comment: There is a way to use OAuth2 between web apps to authenticate from one Web App to another.  I don't have the details of how to do that.  There are a couple of libraries for using OAuth2 with Apps Script.  [apps-script-oauth2 on Git Hub](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2)  OR [the cGoa library](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/goa/walkthroughs)

Comment: You could also send a password to the receiving Web App that allows  "Anyone even anonymous"  Since the communication is encrypted, it should be fine.  So, even though anyone can make a request to the URL, unless that password matches (And you could make it very long), have the code just stop and do nothing.  If the published URL of the receiving Web App is not known to anyone, it's very unlikely that anyone will ever make a request to that URL anyway.

Comment: Here is another resource:  [Using OAuth2 when published as 'user accessing the webapp'](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/goa/walkthroughs/webasuser)

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your experience! Your suggestions and links are extremely helpful!